Normal radical extensions of $\mathbb{Q}$
I have the following question from lecture notes:
Question: Let $L$ be normal radical extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ and $[L:\mathbb{Q}]$ is not a $2$-power. Then $L$ contains a primitive root of unity of odd prime order.
I am going through the lecture notes of Brian Conrad (https://math.stanford.edu/~conrad/210BPage/handouts/radreal.pdf) and somehow feel theorem $2.1$ might be helpful in this case. Can anyone help me solve this ?

$-1 \in L$. Done

Sorry, edited. I meant primitive root of unity. Also how is -1 a root of x^p - 1 ?

$-1$ is a primitive 2nd root of unity.

Edited. Apologies.

If $L$ is normal over $\mathbb Q$ which has characteristic $0$, it must be Galois over $\mathbb Q$. Hence we only need to apply Theorem 2.1 to the case in which $E:=\mathbb Q, K=F:=L$, and $p$ be an odd prime factor of $[L:\mathbb Q]$.

Thank you so much
